# Source client having trouble connecting to serverless Icecast server on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run, icecast

Is it possible to make a serverless Icecast server?

I'm trying to make an internet radio with Icecast on Google's serverless Cloud Run platform. I've put [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/infiniteproject/icecast) in Containter Registry and then created a Cloud Run service with default Icecast port 8000. It all seems to work when visiting Cloud Run's provided URL. Using it I can get to the default Icecast and admin pages.

The problem is trying to connect to the server with a source client (tried using mixxx and butt). I think the problem is with ports since setting the port to 8000 on mixxx gives: ***Socket is busy*** error while butt just simply doesn't connect. Setting the port to 443 on mixxx gives: ***Socket error*** while butt: ***connect: server answered with 411!***

Tried to do the same thing with Compute Engine but just installing Icecast and not a docker image and everything works as intended. As I understand Cloud Run provides a URL for the container (https://example.app) with given port on setup (for Icecast 8000) but source client tries to connect to that URL with its provided port (http://example.app:SOURCE_CLIENT_PORT). So not sure if there's a problem with HTTPS or just need to configure the ports differently.

Answer (score 2):

With Cloud Run you can expose only 1 port externally. By default it's the 8080 port but you can override this [when you deploy your revision](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure-port).

This port is wrapped and behind a front layer on Google Cloud infrastructure, named Google Front End, and exposed with a DNS (*.run.app) on the port 443 (HTTPS).

Thus, you can reach your service only on the exposed port via port 443 wrapping. Any other port will fail.

With Compute Engine, you don't have this limitation, and that's why you haven't issues. Simply open the correct port with firewall rules and enjoy.

Comment: So just out of curiosity, would it be possible to make a serverless Icecast server? Not necessarily on google cloud platform but just in general, is this the limitation of containers and do other cloud providers do something similar?

Comment: I don't know Icecast. Can you share a subset of your config?

Comment: The docker image that is running on Cloud Run has [this icecast.xml](https://hastebin.com/nayahoxovu.xml) and deploying the container the default port is changed to 8000. [Here](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/basic_setup/#setting-up-the-source-client) are the basics of connecting to the server via source client. On mixxx (source client) I've put Cloud Run's provided URL and tried all kinds of ports. Don't know if this information is what you need